# Pycharm (Jetbrains): Disable non-project files access dialog

Tags: phpstorm, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

This window pops up everytime I run pycharm and try to edit something (auto-loading the default project):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/non-project-files-access-dialog.html?origin=old_help

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Phpstorm (also built by Jetbrains).

To fix, search plugin repositories inside your IDE for 'Non Project Files Unlocker' (In Phpstorm you go to Settings->plugins->browse repositories). Install it, and that popup will never show again!

Comment: Yeah! Perhaps add Jetbrains to your tags and title as it may help other Jetbrains users, as it relates to Phpstorm too.

Answer (score 17):

Just remove the **.idea**  folder and reopen your project. It worked for me.

Comment: Rather than disabling the prompt completely, I think this is a better solution.